# How to indicate selectability in an information-focused list

Tags: lists, material-design, selection

My first question, let me know if I should edit!

I'm working on a list-map hybrid, where each item on the list can be selected, to show up on the map (like Yelp).

The list needs to give a fair amount of information at a time, as well as a few actions, and the ability to select multiple items at a time.

The last part is what's giving me issues -- I've just run out of space for the list items. Each list item is about as big as I'd go -- the screen can hold about 2.5 items at a time. If I were to use a checkbox, everything would have to shift over, and it's packed as tightly as I'm comfortable with.

Should be able to:

- select multiple assets at a time, but only one Project/Zone at a time.
- give a fair amount of information
- click the address to go to the asset on the map, click "dashboard" to open up the asset detail view, click the list item itself to select it
- I've thrown together a compact view, with much less information. If this is the way to go, how would the user switch between compact and more information? An "Expand" button on each list item, or a list/detail view toggle?

[image: Ideal, information-heavy view]
[image: Alternate, super-compact view]
[image: Project/Zone information list item]

Comment: It appears the app has at least two different user types:  (1) a company's project manager to assign assets to projects for a given period; and (2) a company's asset maintainers to maintain the assets.  Develop workflows for each user prior to determining what data to display.

Each potential user requires different data to accomplish their tasks.  Consider adding functionality to switch user types and reduce the data displayed for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in information architecture & placing too much information and networks in the list

From what I see **projects**, **groups** and **assets** are collections with items inside.

I think it would be a good practice to introduce another screen - namely the screen of a specific position.

**Why?**

-Increasing readability of information.

-With the amount of iteration, the amount of information to edit, browsing can increase.

-This resolve actual problems.

**The next case i see:**

Assets ∈ Projects ∈ Groups?

if so, the system can be redesigned based on these associations.

-[image]

Comment: OK, so a checklist with a link to a Detail Page? I didn't include it in these images, but there actually is a Detail page for each asset (with a TON of information). Would you suggest just the Compact List and the Detail Pages, or should the List try to show some information?

Comment: List should include only fundamental information - everything + edit should be on Details Page

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas based on your designs that could help:

- Put related components closer so the structure is more clear and compact
- Added expand button (could also use one with a button border, but I think this is clear enough)
- Added expanded view and get even a bit more free space
- I think the envelop icon doesn't add much value

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting! I haven't seen any expandable checklist examples in material design, but this could work out nicely! I'll give it a go and see how it looks. (PS The arrow icon actually does something! The assets have GPS, and the arrow shows the current heading. But I suppose that it might not be very useful -- so it might be OK to remove it)

Comment: In angular you have the option, here I leave the link, hope it helps :) https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview